# CSS Clearing isnt working as expected

Tags: php, html, css

So on my profile.php I have a tab that is loaded and displays the recent 10 messages the user has gotten posted on their profile.
I am trying display each area in a div then float the user that has posted on the page's image floated to the left of the div. But when I do that the entire divs collapses in a weird way. Like shown here:

[image]

So after I had some issues with that I tried to add a clear:both; line of code inside of the image code and this is what it gave me:

[image]

Simply I want the divs to all be the same height and the top div to not have so much height, and its confusing me as to why it actually is that height.

Here is the code that runs in the message div:

```
while ($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          ?>
            <div style="background-color: white; color:black; margin-left:280px; padding:5px; font-family: Sintony; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                <img src="<?=user::idToPic($r['userID'])?>" width="50" height="50" style="float:left;" />
                Test Message

                <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
            </div>

          <?php
        }
```

This is the browsers output for the first message then the second message

[image]

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or plnkr with the html output?

Comment: @Martin that's kind of hard to have done in this case cause there is a load of stuff but I did make the jsfiddle as clustered as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/p23Lzx0p/1/
The main divs to look at are rightarea and leftarea

Comment: Inspect the first row to see what's causing the unwanted space via the browsers developer tools.

Comment: @Vucko added the inspect to the question, but what do you mean by Developer Tools?

Comment: @Jek check the first rows styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `height: 50px;` on every div, or just use classes.

[Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/p23Lzx0p/2/)

Comment: The comments can vary in size so what about when the text is more than the 50 px limit? That would work using 50px per div but what if the content is larger than 50px worth?

Comment: I removed the clear and added your method and it worked :) Thanks mate appreciated `min-height:50px; background-color: white; color:black; margin-left:280px; padding:5px; font-family: Sintony; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:5px;`

Comment: No problem I'm glad I've helped u

Answer (score 1):

Change it to 
    min-height: 50px